# Micelles absorb fat, is there an adjective for this?

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology

"Hygroscopic" means the capacity to absorb water. Is there an adjective to describe the same idea except for the absorption of lipids? Like, when you wash your hands with soap and the soap micelles absorb the bacon grease, for example.

I'd like to say that micelles have ____lipid-absorbing_____ properties.

Comment: Well... Lipophilic?

Comment: *Amphiphilic*, rather than lipophilic, in the particular case of soaps/surfactants, though amphiphilicity implies lipophilicity. There's no real analogy to hygroscopicity, though, since lipids generally are not found in the atmosphere / gas phase.